# Closing delphi app along with another application it opened

Tags: windows, delphi, media-player, delphi-7, forceclose

I have an application that called several other .exe components written in delphi. The question I ask is that is it possible to close the delphi app along with all application it opened (when clicking the '[x]' button)?

Also, obviously, I have learned how to open and close external application, but in several cases like Windows Media Player it just doesn't seem to work... can anyone give me some solution to this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep track of the applications you open, you can post a `WM_QUIT` message to each one's window handle in the `OnClose` event of your Delphi app's main form.

The same should work for Media Player, but it's hard to say when you don't give any information about how you opened it.

Comment: ah, I see, my apologies... it is opened using ShellExecute, but I want to close the application opened at the same moment the delphi application (form, that is) closed using 'red little cross button on the upper right corner' button... is that possible?

Comment: You can tell them to quit (I've cocrected my answer; it should better be `WM_QUIT` instead of `WM_CLOSE`). It will take however long the application needs to shut down, so they may not close at exactly the same moment.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Job Objects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684161%28VS.85%29.aspx) , read the documentation for these functions [`CreateJobObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682409%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [`AssignProcessToJobObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681949%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

> A job object allows groups of processes to be managed as a unit....
>   Examples include enforcing limits such as working set size and process
>   priority or **terminating all processes associated with a job**.